# Project runs fine on emulator(API Level L)but not on my device(API 16)

Tags: android, android-studio

My project is running fine when i run it on emulator of APL Level L but it doesn't run on my device with API 16..It shows "Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]"..i have searched for it and studied other posts but couln't solve it..Here is build.gradle and manifest file

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-L'
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.facebooklogin"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':facebookSDK')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.+'
    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
}
```

Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.facebooklogin"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
          <activity
            android:name=".ViewFlipperSampleActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainFragment"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name="info.androidhive.slidingmenu.SlidingMenu"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `compileSdkVersion 'android-L'` to something else, such as `compileSdkVersion 19`. If you compile with the L Developer Preview, your app can only run on devices or emulators running the L Developer Preview.

Comment: if i change compileSdkVersion 'android-L' to something else it shows error "Error:Execution failed for task ':iBL:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller than version L declared in library com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0-rc1"

Comment: @Stranger You have to change compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
and compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+' in  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'